# SAW Filter for ISM 868MHz

Tags: rf, filter

I'm developing a new version of a 868MHz RF module based on Semtech SX1276 IC. I asking myself if I need to mount a SAW BPF on the RX path. On SX1276 semtech reference design there is a footprint for a SAW filter but is always replace by 0 Ohm jumper (U4 on this exemple) :

[image]

However I read in AN 1200.04 from Semtech :

“Semtech recommend that for most applications, provision be made for a SAW filter since ISM band
devices share frequency spectrum with GSM/GPRS which operates close to the 863 - 870 MHz;”

In EU this is true for GSM900 UL (876 to 915MHz) and also for LTE800 UL (832 to 862MHz).

As far as I know the advantage of SAW filter is that it will improve OoB (Out-of-band rejection) and mains drawbacks is additional costs and additional insertion loss. Tradoff between cost, "range" and reliability.

What is your opinion ?

Best regards